# What does this program do, and how does it do that?

Tags: c++, class, c++11, derived-class

I am having trouble figuring out why this program works. I wrote it based on my notes (OOPP and classes) but I do not understand how exactly it works? I would appreciate any help!

Here is the code:

```
#include <iomanip>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std; 

class Base{
    public:
        void f(int) {std::cout<<"i";}
};
class Derived:Base{
    public:
        void f(double){std::cout<<"d";}
};
int main(){
    Derived d;
    int i=0; 
    d.f(i);
}
```

I have tried making cout statements to show me how everything is passed and runs, but it will not allow me to cout anything.

Comment: [Your code outputs `d`](https://wandbox.org/permlink/gNWFf0YVe1xMXQEe). If you want overload resolution to consider the member functions from `Base` you can say `using Base::Derived;` in `Derived` [like this](https://wandbox.org/permlink/7NizyvpxUdltDmCw)

Comment: but what is your actuall question - what output are you expecting?

Comment: **StackOverflow is not an *"introduction to C++"*.** These trivial things are explained in any beginner [c++ book](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list)

Comment: [What is a debugger and how can it help me diagnose problems?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25385173/what-is-a-debugger-and-how-can-it-help-me-diagnose-problems)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This program defines a class called Base, which has a member function called f that takes an int parameter. It also defines a class called Derived, which inherits from Base and has a member function called f that takes a double parameter.

In the main function, an object of type Derived is created, and an int variable is initialized to 0. The member function f is then called on the Derived object, passing in the int variable as a parameter.

When the member function f is called on the Derived object, the compiler looks for a matching function signature in the Derived class. Since there is a function with the same name and parameter list in the Derived class, that function is called. The function in the Derived class prints out a "d", indicating that it was called.

Comment: almost all wrong